# Identity 2.1 - Check for existing role, default to base user if not in role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am working with this controller code in c#, MVC, and ASP.NET Identity:

```
var role = (from r in context.Roles where r.Name.Contains("SuperAdmin") || r.Name.Contains("ReadOnlyAdmin") select r).FirstOrDefault();
var roleusers = context.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => y.RoleId).Contains(role.Id)).ToList();

                if (roleusers.Find(x => x.Id.Equals(userDetails.Id)) != null)
                {
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(userDetails.Id, "User");    
                }
```

The goal is to have it check to see if the user is a "SuperAdmin" or "ReadOnlyAdmin" and IF NOT, assign it to the user. I am not the greatest with lambdas so I'm sure this is probably something stupid, but I can't figure what's wrong!  Can anyone provide me guidance?

**Edit:** 
Clarification - This is an Administrator editing someone else in the system, not himself.

**Edit 2:** This code path is being used for both updating and registering new users. The suggestions below allow for existing users to be preserved, but new users get NO role. Apologies for not making this clearer before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what **context** is in your question. Normally in ASP.Net Identity, you can do like this -

```
string userId = userDetails.Id;
IList<string> assingedRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(userId);
if (!assingedRoles.Contains("SuperAdmin") && 
    !assingedRoles.Contains("ReadOnlyAdmin"))
{
    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(userId, "User");
}

// UserManager
private AppUserManager UserManager
{
    get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppUserManager>(); }
}
```

Comment: My apologies - the context in this case is the identity context, instantiated like your code example is. This works, but when a new user creation hits this code block they don't get assigned a role whatsoever. I converted the statement to an OR just to see if it works and it gave the same result.

Comment: You need to call `UserManager.UpdateAsync(appUser);` after you add to role.

Comment: This was the solution - my second problem was a separate threat was going out on the side and crashing out the method before it could complete this comparison and update the user. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, I believe you just want something like the following:

```
if (!HttpContext.User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin") || HttpContext.User.IsInRole("ReadOnlyAdmin"))
{
    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(userDetails.Id, "User");
}
```

If the user is NOT in either "SuperAdmin" or "ReadOnlyAdmin" roles, add them to the role "User".

## EDIT

Okay, in that case, try something like this.

```
// get SuperAdmin role
var superAdmin = (from r in context.Roles where r.Name.Contains("SuperAdmin") select r).FirstOrDefault();

// get ReadOnlyAdmin role
var readOnlyAdmin = (from r in context.Roles where r.Name.Contains("ReadOnlyAdmin") select r).FirstOrDefault();

// get users in either role
var roleusers = context.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => y.RoleId).Contains(superAdmin.Id) || x.Roles.Select(z => z.RoleId).Contains(readOnlyAdmin.Id)).ToList();

// if the user doesn't exist in roleusers
if (roleusers.Find(x => x.Id.Equals(userDetails.Id)) == null)
{
    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(userDetails.Id, "User");    
}
```

Comment: Similar to this, but in my case, you're modifying a different user than yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I fully understand your comment. This code will check the user's roles who triggered the action, and assign them the role "User" if they aren't in either Admin role. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: No, this is an administrator editing a different user than himself. So for instance John is editing Sue. The code you suggested works to edit John, but it won't edit Sue if you're logged in as John.

Comment: @Dreamcasting, please see my edit and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Is the "User" role already created? It will have to already exist in the AspNetRoles table for this to work.

Comment: An error is up now: Non-static method requires a target.

Comment: Yes, it is in the table. ---- Update: Looks like the answer above is the answer. Thanks for your contribution to ferreting this one out!

Comment: Hopefully I helped a little bit, at least. Glad you figured it out!